# Shopify Orders API redirects me to login when specifying ID

Tags: php, shopify

I created a private app for my Shopify account so that I can use API to interact with it.

In particular when using the Orders API,
`https://apikey:password@host.myshopify.com/admin/orders.json` returns an empty json, but then when I try to retrieve a specific order using `https://apikey:password@host.myshopify.com/admin/orders/#{id}.json`, I am redirected to the login page.

I have checked that I entered my API username and password correctly. Any help?

Comment: The '#' means a numeric variable. Only it set the id

Comment: Had the same issue, leaving this here for posterity - in my case the request was going to `/orders.json/{id}`; changing it to `/orders/{id}.json` fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using without #. It happend to me also.

https://apikey:password@host.myshopify.com/admin/orders/{id}.json